# Checkbox Trigger Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am having some problem with the checkbox trigger event. Here is how I set up my checkboxes:

```
var content = "<table class=\"filter-table\">";
            content += "<tr><td><label><input  class=\"park_analysis_refined_e\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick=\"toggleOverlayer('park_analysis_refined_e')\" checked='checked'>MP2008 Parks</label></td></tr>" +
                   "<tr><td><div id=\"park_analysis_refined_e\"></div></td></tr>";

            content += "<tr><td><label><input class=\"park_analysis_refined_b_e\"  type=\"checkbox\" id=\"cb_buffer\" onclick=\"toggleOverlayer('park_analysis_refined_b_e')\" >MP2008 Parks Buffer</label></td></tr>" +
                   "<tr><td><div id=\"park_analysis_refined_b_e\"></div></td></tr>";

            content += "<tr><td><label><input class=\"park_analysis_refined_a\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick=\"toggleOverlayer('park_analysis_refined_a')\">DMP2013 Additional Parks</label></td></tr>" +
                   "<tr><td><div id=\"park_analysis_refined_a\"></div></td></tr>";

            content += "<tr><td><label><input class=\"park_analysis_refined_b_a\"  type=\"checkbox\" id=\"cb_additionalBuffer\" onclick=\"toggleOverlayer('park_analysis_refined_b_a')\">DMP2013 Additional Parks Buffer</label></td></tr>" +
                   "<tr><td><div id=\"park_analysis_refined_b_a\"></div></td></tr>";

            content += "</table>"
```

And I have an event delegation to check if there is an event on certain checkbox, it will perform the following method:

```
//Event delegation to maximize/minimize window
            $( "#cb_buffer" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
                   if($('#cb_buffer').is(':checked'))
                   {
                       selectionPGRefined();
                       maximisePGRWindow();
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       minimisePGRWindow();
                   }
               });
            $( "#cb_additionalBuffer" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
                   if($('#cb_additionalBuffer').is(':checked'))
                   {
                       selectionPGRefined();
                       maximisePGRWindow();
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       minimisePGRWindow();
                   }
               });
```

Currently it works well. But the problem occurs when I check two checkboxes and uncheck the others. Basically how my program works is when user check the second checkbox, it will add an overlay map. At the same time, it will call the maximizedWindow method. Same goes to the forth one.

However, when I check the second one and forth one at the same time, and if I uncheck the forth one, the maximizeWindow should display the data by using second checkbox value. Instead, it just close away.

I wonder is there any alternate way for me to loop thru all checkboxes, if there is check or uncheck event, then perform something else.

**EDIT**

```
function toggleOverlayer(id){
switchAnalytics(id);

if ($("."+id).prop("checked")) {
    showOverlayer(id);
} else {
    hideOverlayer(id);
}

}

    function switchAnalytics(id) {
        switch (id) {
            case 'park_analysis_refined_b_a':
                $("#pg_refined_selection").val("1").change();
                break;
            case 'park_analysis_refined_b_e':
                $("#pg_refined_selection").val("0").change();
                break;
        } }

function selectionPGRefined() {
    var selection = document.getElementById('pg_refined_selection');
    var selectionValues = selection.options[selection.selectedIndex].value;
    displayPGRefinedInfo(selectionValues);
}

/*Displaying results of park greenery refined*/
function displayPGRefinedInfo(values) {
    //alert(values);

    var para = "";
    if (values == "0") {
        para = "<br/>"
        para += "<p style='font-size:4.5em; color:#00297A; font-family:ArialVerdana;'>85.0%</p>";
        para += "<p>of residents live within 400m of park</p>";

    } else if (values == "1") {
        para = "<br/>"
        para += "<p style='font-size:4.5em; color:#00297A; font-family:ArialVerdana;'>90.0%</p>";
        para += "<p>of residents live within 400m of park</p>";
        para += "<p>*incl future DUs</p>"

    }
    document.getElementById('parkGreeneryRefinedBoxContent').innerHTML = para;
}
```

Comment: are you sure that your event delegation works? I dont think so, since cb_buffer and cb_additionalBuffer are dynamically created.

Comment: Yeah it did work but only one at a time. If both checked and either one unchecked, the logic part went wrong

Comment: instead of `click` event use `change` event.  It is the best suited for radio/checkboxes.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi The above `event-delegation` approach will work, if it is written after the creation of dynamic-elements [fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/bN4kS/1/).  Otherwise it won't work [fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/bN4kS/)

Comment: @Praveen thats right. But in the first case, he doesnt need event delegation at all

Comment: @Newbie its really hard to understand the problem, it would be fine if you can make a fiddle based on my above comment.

Comment: yeah @Praveen is right, pls share JSfiddle

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot because the codes are very complex as there are many other parallel methods which dependent on each others.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll try to sort things out. There is a lot of code for doing very simple things, but I understand that there might be other functions depending on this code.

First of all, since you are already using jQuery events, it is best not to mix it with the `onclick` property in the markup, so let's remove that and only use jQuery:

```
var content = "<table class=\"filter-table\">";
            content += "<tr><td><label><input  class=\"park_analysis_refined_e\"  type=\"checkbox\" checked='checked'>MP2008 Parks</label></td></tr>" +
                   "<tr><td><div id=\"park_analysis_refined_e\"></div></td></tr>";

            content += "<tr><td><label><input class=\"park_analysis_refined_b_e\"  type=\"checkbox\" id=\"cb_buffer\" >MP2008 Parks Buffer</label></td></tr>" +
                   "<tr><td><div id=\"park_analysis_refined_b_e\"></div></td></tr>";

            content += "<tr><td><label><input class=\"park_analysis_refined_a\"  type=\"checkbox\">DMP2013 Additional Parks</label></td></tr>" +
                   "<tr><td><div id=\"park_analysis_refined_a\"></div></td></tr>";

            content += "<tr><td><label><input class=\"park_analysis_refined_b_a\"  type=\"checkbox\" id=\"cb_additionalBuffer\">DMP2013 Additional Parks Buffer</label></td></tr>" +
                   "<tr><td><div id=\"park_analysis_refined_b_a\"></div></td></tr>";

            content += "</table>"
```

Next, it's probably better if you use the `change` event instead `click`. I will update the function to handle all of the checkboxs, not just the second and fourth, as explained above. The code previously executed from the `onclick` markup property will be moved inside this handler. Secondly, you should merge those two events because they are doing basically the same thing, so try to avoid unnecessary code repetition. Thirdly, inside the event handler you should check if either of the checkboxes are checked, not just the current one. Here is the code:

```
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function (event) {
    toggleOverlayer($(this).prop('id'));

    if ($('#cb_buffer').is(':checked') || $('#cb_additionalBuffer').is(':checked')) {
        selectionPGRefined();
        maximisePGRWindow();
    }
    else {
        minimisePGRWindow();
    }
});
```

Lastly, let's change the `switchAnalytics` function to implement your logic about setting the value to 0 or 1:

```
function switchAnalytics(id) {
    var id_a = "park_analysis_refined_b_a";
    var id_e = "park_analysis_refined_b_e";
    var isChecked_a = $("#" + id_a).is(":checked");
    var isChecked_e = $("#" + id_e).is(":checked");

    if (id == id_a || id == id_e) {
        var newValue = "";
        if (isChecked_a && isChecked_e)
            newValue = id == id_a ? "1" : "0";
        else if (isChecked_a)
            newValue = "1";
        else if (isChecked_e)
            newValue = "0";

        $("#pg_refined_selection").val(newValue).change();
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: It did works but somehow it went conflict with my toggleOverlayer. My conflict mean if my second checkbox was checked, the dropdownlist value should be 0. For the forth, it supposed to be 1. Instead, it went upside down. Check my edited portion for toggleOverlayer()

Comment: I think the problem is on the `selectionPGRefined` function. Can you post that too?

Comment: Any clues? I think some event handler trigger part went wrong

Comment: what should be the value of dropdown list when both checkboxes are checked?

Comment: @StefanoDalpiaz I cannot remove the onclick as it is binded to some other parts of my codes. If removed, it will cause error since my first checkbox is checked by default

Comment: I have updated the answer with a few more details to try and address the issue with the dropdown.

Comment: Ok then leave the onclick there and see what happens. You may try to comment out the first line in the jQuery event handler (`toggleOverlayer($(this).prop('id'));`)

Comment: No it does not work. The drop down list value will just stick to 0 and does not change at all

Comment: What logic do you need exactly for the checkbox selection? I understand that the dropdown needs to have value 1 when one of the checkboxes is selected, and 0 when the other one is. What happens when both of them are checked, or neither?

Comment: Let's say now I checked the second and then the forth, the value for ddl should be 1. If I checked it in the other way around, the ddl should be 0. When I uncheck the forth and left second checked, the ddl should be 0. It went the other way around if I left the forth checked. But right now the problem is, I checked both, and I uncheck the second one and left the forth checked, it show ddl value 0 but not 1. Because when I uncheck the second one, I called the toggleOverlayer and passed in the wrong value. Is there anyway to overcome it?

Comment: I have edited the `switchAnalytics` function in the answer. See if that works for you.

Comment: @StefanoDalpiaz Nope it does not work. It only work with switch statement I think

Answer (score 0):

try delegate like this:

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

try like this:

```
 $( document ).on( "change",'#cb_buffer', function( event ) {
                   if($(this).is(':checked'))
                   {
                       selectionPGRefined();
                       maximisePGRWindow();
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       minimisePGRWindow();
                   }
               });
 $( document).on( "change",'#cb_additionalBuffer', function( event ) {
                   if($(this).is(':checked'))
                   {
                       selectionPGRefined();
                       maximisePGRWindow();
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       minimisePGRWindow();
                   }
               });
```

<kbd>[api delegate doc](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)</kbd>
<kbd>[sample demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/109/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

User multiple jQuery selector like below

```
$( "#cb_buffer, #cb_additionalBuffer" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
  // here check if any of the checkbox is already checked then don't do any action
   var cb_buffer_checked = $("#cb_buffer").is(':checked');
   var cb_additionalBuffer_checked = $("#cb_additionalBuffer").is(':checked');

      // if checkbox unchecked then update option for other checked checkbox
      if(!$(this).is(':checked');)
      {
      // set option for checked checkbox
      if(cb_additionalBuffer_checked)
        switchAnalytics($("#cb_additionalBuffer").attr('id'));

      if(cb_buffer_checked )
        switchAnalytics($("#cb_buffer").attr('id'));
      }

      if(cb_buffer_checked || cb_additionalBuffer_checked)
      {
        selectionPGRefined();
        maximisePGRWindow();            
      }
      else
      {
       minimisePGRWindow();
      }

 });
```

Comment: This just shorten and make my codes neater but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: So you want to keep window maximised if any one of cb_buffer and cb_additionalBuffer is checked and minimized if both are unchecked, right? please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yeah, but then the other problem occurs. See Stefano Dalpiaz post. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to show dropdown value for last checked checkbox, i mean if first checkbox checked after second one then option value = 0 and if vice versa then option value=1. But then what if both gets unchecked? did you handle this by calling minimisePGRWindow()?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. But let's say I checked both, then I uncheck one, the program should check if the other one was checked, if checked, then show that value

Comment: But from your codes, the maximize not even executing

Comment: yes because there is one checkbox checked already and maximise done for it.. hence just updating dropdown value for last checked checkbox

Comment: But the problem is now the maximized window not even showing up.

Comment: oh ... try this ... i thought once maximise opened it won't go away

Comment: Sure thing, but the same problem occurred as Stefano Dapliaz post